# require_auth() not working as expected

Tags: smart-contract, accounts, permissions

I adapted the hello contract, expanding with `require_auth()` and added an additional account `oliver` that should be able to execute the action `hashin` on behalf of the contract owner `doctest1`. I adjusted the permission within the account `doctest1`.

When I try to push action `hashin`, I get an error:

```
cleos push action doctest1 hashin '["oliver"]' -p oliver@active
```

Error 3090004: Missing required authority
Ensure that you have the related authority inside your transaction!;
If you are currently using 'cleos push action' command, try to add the relevant authority using -p option.
Error Details:
missing authority of active
pending console output:

my contract looks like this:

```
 #include "../include/doctest1.hpp" 

ACTION doctest1::hi(name nm) {   print_f("Name : %\n", nm); }

ACTION doctest1::check(name nm) {
   print_f("Name : %\n", nm);
   eosio::check(nm == "doctest1"_n, "check name not equal to `doctest1`");
 }

  ACTION doctest1::hashin(std::string h) {
   require_auth(_self);
   print_f("my hash: %", h.c_str());
 }

 EOSIO_DISPATCH(doctest1, (hi)(check)(hashin))
```

doctest1 account permission:

`cleos get account -j doctest1
{
  "account_name": "doctest1",
  "head_block_num": 1923524,
  "head_block_time": "2019-03-15T13:12:15.000",
  "privileged": false,
  "last_code_update": "2019-03-15T09:33:07.500",
  "created": "2019-03-14T15:00:38.000",
  "ram_quota": -1,
  "net_weight": -1,
  "cpu_weight": -1,
  "net_limit": {
    "used": -1,
    "available": -1,
    "max": -1
  },
  "cpu_limit": {
    "used": -1,
    "available": -1,
    "max": -1
  },
  "ram_usage": 61719,
  "permissions": [{
      "perm_name": "active",
      "parent": "owner",
      "required_auth": {
        "threshold": 2,
        "keys": [{
            "key": "EOS6nZrpo4hurCZX88njkM5R2i8dmvjerSMfsMoEhK7yBHApqQSDR",
            "weight": 2
          },{
            "key": "EOS7pP22kEX2fmgthMeJLT2uz4nwnw6Zu33qC2Pd6w1p4wnYUswyc",
            "weight": 2
          }
        ],
        "accounts": [{
            "permission": {
              "actor": "oliver",
              "permission": "active"
            },
            "weight": 2
          }
        ],
        "waits": []
      }
    },{
      "perm_name": "owner",
      "parent": "",
      "required_auth": {
        "threshold": 1,
        "keys": [{
            "key": "EOS6nZrpo4hurCZX88njkM5R2i8dmvjerSMfsMoEhK7yBHApqQSDR",
            "weight": 1
          }
        ],
        "accounts": [],
        "waits": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "total_resources": null,
  "self_delegated_bandwidth": null,
  "refund_request": null,
  "voter_info": null
}`

What do I need to adjust so `doctest1` account can serve as a *group* of accounts (growing with accounts that need to execute hashin)?

Answer (score 1):

If several users need to be able to use this function, but they have to authorize themselves to use it, then you would write your function as follows:

```
ACTION doctest1::hashin(eosio::name user, std::string h){
  require_auth(user);
  print_f("my hash: %", h.c_str());
}
```

Then the user would call the function as follows:

```
cleos push action doctest1 hashin '["oliver","oliver"]' -p oliver@active
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.
In your solution, how do I distinguish accounts that should be able to execute the action from those that shouldn't?
How can I build a group of allowed users/account?

Comment: So you would create a `multi_index`, containing a list of allowed accounts, and then you would use `eosio::check` to confirm that an account was a part of the `multi_index table`. You can find more information at https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.5.0/

Comment: Yes, I could have a table containing account information to check against, but that's rather a workaround isn't it? Imagine you would need a table within each and every contract just to manage access control, that is a huge overhead imo.
I would rather have someone explain how I can access the additional permission I have implemented in the doctest1(@active) account and make use of it? Thus geting closer in undestanding the permissioning system in eos.
If I'm not able to even understand this small step of require_auth(), how far would I get with custom permissions and require_auth2() ^^

Comment: so the question might be cleare if I ask:
why does require_auth(_self); 
not see, that there are additional entries in the permisssion: doctest1@active ?
and in consequence allow accout oliver execute the action.

Comment: In what sense is the account `oliver` connected to the account `doctest1`. You say you have adjusted the permission, could you show the code by editing your question which you used to set the new permission. Can you show the result of `cleos get account doctest1`? The overhead for using tables is not so large and it is standard practise as of right now in the smart contract dev world. Are you suggesting that the active permission on the `doctest1` account is multisignature, with a threshold of 1 so that anyone who is on the list can use the account with active permission?

Comment: In the above code, if you scroll down a bit you can see the output of cleos get account -j doctest1.
and yes, I tried to achieve exactly what you have described by adding the account of oliver to the active permission of doctest1 and was expecting, that like this doctest1 could be used as a container/group of accounts that I want grant permission through.
As you can see above, I set the threshold to 2 but also the weight to 2, later I tried to set both to 1 but it didn't work either.
I didn't think of it as being multisig, but if you could show me the direction of having multisig with

Comment: .. just 1 signature, that would help me sooo much :)
I can't explain why I probably would prefer this method over having a table, maybe it seems "more secure" as tables are so easily editable.
Do you know the pros and cons of using tables over multisig with weight = threshold? why has using tables become standard practise?
Anyways great reply, thanks alot, will dive into multisig, I guess I wont be able to use require_auth() in that context?

Answer (score 0):

you have put the  "require_auth(_self);" , that means the action will be only executed by the deployed contract account. The keyword "_self" allow only one account which is the name of the deployed contract account.
If u want to push that action with ur oliver account just comment the line "require_auth(_self);"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is not far from what I need.
How do I make the deploy contract account be a group account?
With the cleos set permission ... I know how to add other account to said active permission, what I don't know is, how to make my code aware of those additional accounts included in the active permission of the contract deployment account?
That seems somehow very difficult to figure out.